# \citep is not working

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am new to LaTeX (MiKTeX version) and try to get authoryear citation e.g. (Hugh et al., 2009) using \citep{MCOSW}. But rather it shows the whole list of authors with year at the end e.g.
(Hugh Glaser, Afraz Jafri, and Ian Millard, April 2009). How can I force it to show et al. I am using natbib package. List of packages along with style and bib is mentioned below:

```
\usepackage{epsfig}           
\usepackage{graphics}         
\usepackage{subfigure}           
\usepackage{fancyheadings}          
\usepackage{float}          
\usepackage{times}       
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsthm,xspace}         
\usepackage{algorithmic}         
\usepackage{algorithm2e}        
\usepackage{verbatim}        
\usepackage{appendix}         
\usepackage[round,authoryear,comma,sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}       
\usepackage{hyperref}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

@article {MCOSW,
author = "{Hugh Glaser, Afraz Jafri, and Ian Millard}",
title = "{Managing co-reference on the semantic web.}",
journal = "{In WWW2009 Workshop: Linked Data on the Web (LDOW2009)}",
year = "{April 2009}",
}
```

Could anyone of you please help.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! When posting questions about code to this groups, it's helpful to post an entire Minimum Working Example (MWE) rather than code snippets. The MWE should only contain the essential set of instructions. Trimming the code to the bare minimum is both good discipline *and* a courtesy to the people you're asking for help.

Answer (score 16):

Don't overuse braces, and treat your BibTeX keys as data (don't mix months and years together), rather than formatted output. If you have a list of authors, separate each name with an **and**, and let BibTeX figure out how to split them.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article {MCOSW,
author = "Hugh Glaser and Afraz Jafri and Ian Millard",
title = "Managing co-reference on the semantic web",
journal = "WWW2009 Workshop: Linked Data on the Web (LDOW2009)",
month = "April",
year = "2009",
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
I once read \citep{MCOSW}.

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Notice that BibTeX:

- puts the correct *et al.* in my citation
- puts commas where needed in the bibliography listing
- puts a period at the end of the article title
- uses the month and year if the bibliography style requires it (and both items are known)

See also Andy Roberts' [Bibliographies - Getting to grips with LaTeX](http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/bibliographies), particularly the "Authors" section.

Comment: Click the checkmark by my answer to accept it when you get the chance? That will take your question off the unanswered list.