# BibTeX single author entries with two periods

Tags: bibtex

Using BibTeX, I am trying to edit a .bst file to not produce two periods following the author name of a single author entry. For example the following entry...

```
@ARTICLE{Yeh2004,
  author = {Yeh, P. J.},
  title = {Rapid evolution of a sexually selected trait following population
    establishment in a novel habitat},
  journal = {Evolution},
  year = {2004},
  volume = {58},
  pages = {166-174},
  number = {1},
  endnotereftype = {Journal Article},
  issn = {0014-3820}
}
```

...produces this given my current .bst file:
[image]

Anyone know how I can edit this for single authors, yet maintain a period to separate entries with multiple authors from the subsequent year? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please state the *name* of the `.bst` file you're trying to edit. There must be hundreds, if not thousands, of `.bst` files available in various repositories.

Comment: The `.bst` file I'm using is `evolution.bst` from this website http://www.lecb.ncifcrf.gov/~toms/latex.html which I have made some small edits to in an attempt to meet the formatting requirements. I actually tried to delete this post as in retrospect I feel it is too narrow in scope and might not help future users but was unable to as it's already been answered. Either way thanks in advance for any help/advice you can offer.

Comment: Thanks for providing this link. When I run a small example bib file with evolution.bst through latex and bibtex, I am unable to reproduce the problem behavior you describe. Did a bug maybe creep in during your attempts to edit the .bst file? Just guessing, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't post anything about your .bst, here's evidence that it does work with one of the normal styles (cbe):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{cbe}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Yeh2004,
  author = {Pamela J. Yeh},
  title = {Rapid evolution of a sexually selected trait following population
    establishment in a novel habitat},
  journal = {Evolution},
  year = {2004},
  volume = {58},
  pages = {166-174},
  number = {1},
  endnotereftype = {Journal Article},
  issn = {0014-3820}
}
@ARTICLE{YehEntirely2004,
  author = {Pamela J. Yeh and Someone Else Entirely},
  title = {More rapid evolution of a sexually selected trait following population
    establishment in a novel habitat},
  journal = {Evolution},
  year = {2004},
  volume = {58},
  pages = {175-179},
  number = {1},
  endnotereftype = {Journal Article},
  issn = {0014-3820}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

First I read \citet{Yeh2004}, then \citet{YehEntirely2004}.

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

I've also got some general BibTeX advice over at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42699/3345), which explains the changes I made to your .bib.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Mike. I guess I was curious if anyone could point me in the right direction for editing the .bst file to account for entries that have differing numbers of authors but this is also quite useful. Cheers!

Comment: Since the cbe style appears to do what you want (at least from the description), you could start from there and modify it. Then when something breaks, you can ask another question (or modify this one) to ask why changing a particular part caused the breakage.