# I am not getting ampersand (&) with citep in latex; instead it comes with "and" when using citep. I am using \bibliographystyle{agsm}

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, natbib, harvard-style

```
\documentclass[11pt, authoryear, longnamesfirst]{elsarticle}
 \usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib} 
    @article{fransoo2020exiting, 
        title={Exiting a COVID-19 Lockdown: The Bumpy Road Ahead for Many Supply Chains}, 
        author={Fransoo, Jan C and Udenio, Maximiliano}, 
        journal={Available at SSRN 3590153}, 
        year={2020} } 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    
    \textbf{Getting problem in using Harvard Style referencing}
    
    \begin{enumerate}
        
        \item All mentions of authors in the running text should be in the format of Author’s Last Name (year), and should include the word “and” rather than an ampersand (\&). Below is the example of running text:
        
        \begin{itemize} 
            \item \cite{fransoo2020exiting} says that this work is right. Here “and” is coming in the citation which is right. This is an example of running text citation. 
        \end{itemize}
        
        \item The problem is happening with In-text citations. In Harvard style, the requirement is as described below: In-text citations for sources with multiple authors should use an ampersand (\&) to join the last two. Below is the example of in text citation: authors’ names.
        
        \begin{itemize} 
            \item This work is exemplary \citep{fransoo2020exiting}. Here the desired output as per Harvard style is “\&” but “and” is coming in between the authors name. This is an example of In-text citation. 
        \end{itemize}
        
    \end{enumerate}
    
    \bibliographystyle{agsm} 
    \bibliography{ref}
 \end{document}

\endinput
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a minimal compilable example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix.

Comment: see [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42696/citep-is-not-working)

Comment: The MWE link I am sharing below.

Comment: Thanks. Done that

Comment: In summary, you want “and” spelled out with `\citet` (or `\cite`) but that it becomes “&” with `\citep`?

Comment: @egreg Yes right. "and" with \citet (or \cite) and "&"with \citep. Also, using apacite with \documentclass{article} gave me the desired result. But apacite is not working \documentclass{elsarticle}. If there is any way as how apacite can be used with \documentclass{elsarticle}, that can also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine `\harvardand` to issue `and` with `\citet` (that's the same as `\cite`) and `\&` with `\citep`. It's necessary to patch the two commands to insert the setting of a conditional. The macro `\harvardand` has to be made `\protected`, so it's not untimely expanded.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{fransoo2020exiting, 
  title={Exiting a {COVID-19} Lockdown: The Bumpy Road Ahead for Many Supply Chains}, 
  author={Fransoo, Jan C. and Udenio, Maximiliano}, 
  journal={Available at SSRN 3590153}, 
  year={2020},
} 
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt, authoryear, longnamesfirst]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifharvardand@ampersand@
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \xpatchcmd{\citet}
    {\begingroup}
    {\begingroup\harvardand@ampersand@false}
    {}{}%
  \xpatchcmd{\citep}
    {\begingroup}
    {\begingroup\harvardand@ampersand@true}
    {}{}%
  \protected\def\harvardand{\ifharvardand@ampersand@\&\else and\fi}%
}
% also make & to appear in the bibliography
\AddToHook{env/thebibliography/begin}{\harvardand@ampersand@true}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\textbf{Getting problem in using Harvard Style referencing}
    
\begin{enumerate}
        
\item All mentions of authors in the running text should be in the format of 
  Author’s Last Name (year), and should include the word “and” rather than
  an ampersand (\&). Below is the example of running text:

\item \cite{fransoo2020exiting} says that this work is right. Here “and”
  is coming in the citation which is right. This is an example of running
  text citation. 
        
\item The problem is happening with In-text citations. In Harvard style,
  the requirement is as described below: In-text citations for sources
  with multiple authors should use an ampersand (\&) to join the last
  two. Below is the example of in text citation: authors’ names.

\item This work is exemplary \citep{fransoo2020exiting}. Here the
   desired output as per Harvard style is “\&” but “and” is coming
   in between the authors name. This is an example of In-text citation. 

\end{enumerate}
    
\bibliographystyle{agsm} 
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Very strange style. Personally, I'd never use & other than in commercial names, certainly not in citations.

If you have a version of LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01, you can use

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\harvardand@ampersand@true}
```

instead of the line

```
\AddToHook{env/thebibliography/begin}{\harvardand@ampersand@true}
```

However, this seems like an XY-problem. You want to use APA style, not Harvard.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{fransoo2020exiting, 
  title={Exiting a {COVID-19} Lockdown: The Bumpy Road Ahead for Many Supply Chains}, 
  author={Fransoo, Jan C. and Udenio, Maximiliano}, 
  journal={Available at SSRN 3590153}, 
  year={2020},
} 
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt,nonatbib]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Getting problem in using Harvard Style referencing}
    
\begin{enumerate}
        
\item All mentions of authors in the running text should be in the format of 
  Author’s Last Name (year), and should include the word “and” rather than
  an ampersand (\&). Below is the example of running text:

\item \cite{fransoo2020exiting} says that this work is right. Here “and”
  is coming in the citation which is right. This is an example of running
  text citation. 
        
\item The problem is happening with In-text citations. In Harvard style,
  the requirement is as described below: In-text citations for sources
  with multiple authors should use an ampersand (\&) to join the last
  two. Below is the example of in text citation: authors’ names.

\item This work is exemplary \citep{fransoo2020exiting}. Here the
   desired output as per Harvard style is “\&” but “and” is coming
   in between the authors name. This is an example of In-text citation. 

\end{enumerate}
    
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @egreg...it worked. This is Decision Sciences Journal requirement.

Comment: I also need to replace the "and"in bibliography with "&". Please suggest solution for this.

Comment: @mathslove I added the necessary code

Comment: \AddToHook{env/thebibliography/begin}{\harvardand@ampersand@true} is showing error during compilation

Comment: @mathslove You have an outdated TeX system. I add also how to cope with this situation.

Comment: \AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\harvardand@ampersand@true} This worked. Thanks a ton for all the help.

Comment: I have one more query. I am getting bold volume number in bibliography. How to unbold the volume number and change it to italic?

Comment: Also is there any way to use apacite with \documentclass{elsarticle}? apacite provides all the functionalities I have asked for so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127748/discussion-between-mathslove-and-egreg).

Comment: @mathslove The code for APA style has been added.

Comment: You are genius @egreg. All the problems are now solved. Thanks a lot.